# После компиляции файл начал требовать права администратора

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw, root

После компиляции проекта на Qt (5.7.2) + mingw53_32 получал вполне обыкновенный исполняемый файл. Но при последней компиляции возникла проблема, что полученный файл мог быть запущенный исключително с правами администратора. Проблема возникла второй раз. Общих действий между ними не припомню.
pro файл проекта.

```
QT       += core gui network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = <progname>
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp
HEADERS  += widget.h
RESOURCES += \
    res.qrc
RC_FILE = info.rc
```

Подключены были такие библиотеки 
QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QMessageBox
QDir, QFile
QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkReply, QNetworkRequest
QTimer, QProcess, QVersionNumber, QCoreApplication

Правильно сформулировать вопрос для гугла у меня не вышло. Не нашел ничего хотя бы немного похожее на мою ситуацию. 
Может кто-то может хотя бы указать "куда воевать"?
Прикладываю файл rc

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON "icon.ico"

#include <windows.h>

#define VER_FILEVERSION             0,7,0
#define VER_FILEVERSION_STR         "0.7.0.0\0"
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION          2,0,0
#define VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR      "2.0.0\0"
#define VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR     "notneed"
#define VER_INTERNALNAME_STR        "notneed"
#define VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR      "Copyright (C) 2017, notneed"
#define VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR    "notneed.exe"
#define VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR         "notneed"

VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION     VER_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION  VER_PRODUCTVERSION
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "FileDescription",    VER_FILEDESCRIPTION_STR
            VALUE "FileVersion",        VER_FILEVERSION_STR
            VALUE "InternalName",       VER_INTERNALNAME_STR
            VALUE "LegalCopyright",     VER_LEGALCOPYRIGHT_STR
            VALUE "OriginalFilename",   VER_ORIGINALFILENAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductName",        VER_PRODUCTNAME_STR
            VALUE "ProductVersion",     VER_PRODUCTVERSION_STR
        END
    END

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1252
    END
END
```

Comment: А что он говорит если не от админа запускать?

Comment: а в  info.rc случайно манифест не подключаете?

Comment: нет, в rc манифест не добавлял. Да и заработал он бы вроде только с компилятором VS. Потому и указал дополнительно, что компилил mingw.

Comment: а вот target ещё неплохо показать. Он случайно не называется setup.exe или install.exe? (да, я вижу, что в info.rc он называется notpeed. Но мало чего)

Comment: В рц в основном для отображения инфы по продукту, ну и иконка. В таргете просто название, без .exe и того подобное. К примеру "testingProgramm". Без кавычек)

Comment: так testingProgramm или как. Пожалуйста, напишите полное имя

Comment: Да. Таргет не менялся с самого создания проекта. И он был как с правами администратора так и без них одинаковым. @KoVadim

Comment: Учитывая, как Вы скрываете имя, оно явно интересное. И в нем вся соль.

Comment: да. Я не вижу теперь ни одной причины, почему это нужно было скрывать. Подобное поведение наблюдается, если либо добавлен специальный манифест к файлу, либо имя файла попадает под спецмаску (либо приложение само попросило это). Omvel - малоизвестная малварь, которая используется для контроля за сотрудниками. Она случайно на машине не установлена?

Comment: К чему тут она? Установлена она или нет, после компиляции она вполне компилилась в обычный файл, без требования повышеных прав, после этого никакой софт дополнительно не ставился. У вас крайне странные вопросы, @KoVadim .

Answer (score 1):

Причину проблемы не нашел. Потому решил создать манифест, где принудительно указывал, что программа не нуждается в доп. привилегиях.

Создал файл манифеста manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

А в файле .rc добавил в начале строку:

> 1 24 ".\manifest.xml"